# reading too many small files in pyspark taking so much of time

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

I have written pyspark job to load files present in s3 bucket . In s3 there are too many small files , I am reading file one by one in spark . I am reading a file one one by one as I am adding one column that column has value of bucket path where file is present . Due to this spark job is spending so much of time as it is busy iterating file one by one .

below is code for that :

```
for filepathins3 in awsfilepathlist:
    data = spark.read.format("parquet").load(filepathins3) \
                    .withColumn("path_s3", lit(filepathins3))
```

above code is taking so much of time as it is spending much of time reading file one by one , If I provide list of file's path then spark job finishes quickly , but with this approach I can not add column that has filepath as value in the data-frame .

is there way to solve above problem in pyspark job only , rather than creating a separate program to read files and then club and load into spark .

Comment: I was going to suggest loading awsfilepathlist into a DataFrame and then using mapPartitions but I cannot find this in pyspark.
You may be able to create an RDD out of awsfilepathlist (`sc.parallelize(awsfilepathlist)`) and then use RDD.mapPartitions. When you want the RDD returned as a DataFrame just use the `.toDF()` method on the RDD.

Comment: Now that I think about it, if this runs quickly when you provide a list of paths, perhaps the issue isn't with Spark but rather with how you are loading the paths in the first place. Have you tried to load the paths into a list (`for filepathins3 in list(awsfilepathlist):`)?

Comment: yes issue is with iteration not with spark , passing list of files help but I am adding a column in each file that contains value as file path of s3 , this is reason I have to iterate each file and create column in file and add value that is s3 file path .

Comment: if there's something that is unique to each file (in the data), you could load all the files in a single dataframe and then add the paths based on that.

Comment: there is data that keeps changing and schema is fixed for all files .

Comment: Seems to me the problem then isn't Spark its how you load the list of paths. Do you mind sharing that code?

Answer (score 2):

If the goal is to get the file path, Spark already has a function `input_file_name()` :

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

data = spark.read.parquet('s3path').withColumn("input_file", input_file_name())
```

Comment: but to apply this I would have to read file one by one or I can provide list of file like spark.read.parquet(*awsfilepathlist) and now command will be like : data = spark.read.parquet(*awsfilepathlist).withColumn("input_file", input_file_name())  ? would this work , and what would be input_file_name() , in this case ?

Comment: do all of your files reside in the same bucket ? if so, then just put the path to those files instead of `s3Path` ( i.e. `'s3://some_bucket_name/folder/another_folder_where files are/'`). The `input_file_name()` will give you the location (path) of that file.

Comment: Did you try it?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do

```
spark.read.parquet(*awsfilepathlist)
```

Comment: yes this option is already tired , problem is not providing list of paths to spark , since I have to read file and add one column that will have file path added as value . due to that reason I have to iterate file one by one to read and add new column in each file that has value as file path .